# Taxonomy Drill-Down / Plugin Help - hierarchical queries within plugin?

Tags: plugins, taxonomy, query, hierarchical, children

I hope this question doesn't make me look too stupid!

I am using a plugin called 'Query Multiple Taxonomies' -- it's a fantastic plugin and is written extraordinarily well. http://wordpress.org/plugins/query-multiple-taxonomies/

It does *just* about everything that I need it to do save one small thing. I've been trying to figure out how to accomplish this last bit for a while now, and I decided that it was time to ask for some help.

You can view the section I'm working on here: http://tunagaming.dyndns.org/?section=tutorials

The drill-down works very well. This is how it is currently set up:

- First page shows platforms.
- Second page shows genres
- Third page shows sub-genres.

This is how I want it to work, except that each of those are custom taxonomies, and I would like to eliminate 'sub-genres' completely in favor of a hierarchical 'genres' taxonomy.

So ultimately, I would like for the drill-down to work like this:

- First page shows platforms.
- Second page shows ONLY parent terms in the taxonomy 'genres'
- Third page shows children of selected parent.

All of this is being called in an archive.php file. Here is the code for reference:

```
<?php if (is_multitax( array('section', 'platforms', 'genre') ) ){

the_widget('Taxonomy_Drill_Down_Widget', array(
    'title' => '',
    'mode' => 'lists',
    'taxonomies' => array('subgenre')
));?>
    <div id="postList">
    <h2>Query Results</h2>
    <?php if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <ul><a title="<?php the_title();?>" href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><li>
        <span class="image"><?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($page->ID, 'thumbnail'); ?></span>
        <span class="content">
        <h3><?php the_title();?></h3>
        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
        </span>

    </ul></li></a>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    </div>

<?php 
}
elseif (is_multitax( array('section', 'platforms') ) ) {

the_widget('Taxonomy_Drill_Down_Widget', array(
    'title' => '',
    'mode' => 'lists',
    'taxonomies' => array('genre')
));
?>

    <div id="postList">
    <h2>Query Results</h2>
    <?php if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <ul><a title="<?php the_title();?>" href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><li>
        <span class="image"><?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($page->ID, 'thumbnail'); ?></span>
        <span class="content">
        <h3><?php the_title();?></h3>
        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
        </span>

    </ul></li></a>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    </div>
<?php
} 
else {
the_widget('Taxonomy_Drill_Down_Widget', array(
    'title' => '',
    'mode' => 'lists',
    'taxonomies' => array('platforms') // list of taxonomy names
));
?>

    <div id="postList">
    <h2>Latest Entries</h2>
    <?php if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <ul><a title="<?php the_title();?>" href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><li>
        <span class="image"><?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($page->ID, 'thumbnail'); ?></span>
        <span class="content">
        <h3><?php the_title();?></h3>
        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
        </span>

    </ul></li></a>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

I would love some help in figuring this out, or even some fresh ideas on how to achieve this drill-down. I'm not asking for anyone to code it for me, but it is just a bit over my head. I'm okay with PHP -- not great. So a nudge in the right direction would also be very helpful!

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

For what it's worth, I believe the answer lies in the plugin's walker.php file. I could be wrong, but here's the code I've been studying this morning:

```
function display_element( $element, &$children_elements, $max_depth, $depth=0, $args, &$output ) {

        if ( !$element )
            return;

        $id_field = $this->db_fields['id'];

        $id = $element->$id_field;

        $child_output = '';

        // descend only when the depth is right and there are childrens for this element
        if ( ($max_depth == 0 || $max_depth > $depth+1 ) && isset( $children_elements[$id]) ) {

            foreach ( $children_elements[ $id ] as $child ) {
                $this->display_element( $child, $children_elements, $max_depth, $depth + 1, $args, $child_output );
            }

            unset( $children_elements[ $id ] );
        }

        $this->single_el( $output, $element, $depth, $child_output );
    }

    function single_el( &$output, $term, $depth, $child_output ) {
        $data = $this->specific_data( $term, $depth );

        $data = array_merge( $data, array(
            'term-name' => $term->name,
            'is-selected' => in_array( $term->slug, $this->selected_terms ) ? array(true) : false,
            'depth' => $depth,
        ) );

        if ( !empty( $child_output ) ) {
            $data['children']['child-list'] = $child_output;
        }

        $full_data = new QMT_Data_Container( $this->taxonomy, $term, $data );

        $output .= Taxonomy_Drill_Down_Widget::mustache_render( $this->walker_type . '-item.html', $full_data );
    }

    abstract function specific_data( $term, $depth );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had done some work for my upcoming theme which shows category tree (Taxonomy drill down) from custom taxonomy. You can show it on taxonomy page or on category page.

```
if(! defined('TH_TAX_TYPE')) define('TH_TAX_TYPE','your-tax-type');

function is_decendent($term_id,$main_parent) {
   $terms= get_term_by('id', $term_id,TH_TAX_TYPE);
   $parent_term=  get_term_by('id', $terms->parent,TH_TAX_TYPE);
  $grand_parent_term=  get_term_by('id',$parent_term->parent,TH_TAX_TYPE);

if($terms || $grand_parent_term){
    if($grand_parent_term->term_id==$main_parent){
        return TRUE;
    }
  }
return FALSE;
}



 function category_tree() {
    global $term;
    $get_current_term_info= get_term_by('slug', $term,TH_TAX_TYPE);

$all_category=  get_terms(TH_TAX_TYPE);
$out_put='<ul class="category-tree">
  <li><a href="'.get_option('all_cat_link').'">'.__('All Files','themeshive').'</a></li>';
foreach ($all_category as $main_cat) {
    if($main_cat->parent=='0'){
        $out_put.='<li><a href="'.get_term_link($main_cat).'">'.$main_cat->name.'</a>';
        $sub_cats=get_terms(TH_TAX_TYPE, array('parent'=>$main_cat->term_id ));
        if($sub_cats ){
            if($main_cat->slug==$term || $main_cat->term_id ==$get_current_term_info->parent || is_decendent($get_current_term_info->term_id,$main_cat->term_id)){
            $out_put.='<ul>';
            foreach ($sub_cats as $sub_cat) {
                $out_put.='<li><a href="'.get_term_link($sub_cat).'">'.$sub_cat->name.'</a> 
                    <small>('.$sub_cat->count.')</small>';
                    $sub_sub_cats=  get_terms(TH_TAX_TYPE, array('parent'=>$sub_cat->term_id));
                     if($sub_cat->slug==$term || $sub_cat->term_id ==$get_current_term_info->parent){
                    if($sub_sub_cats){
                        $out_put.='<ul>';
                        foreach ($sub_sub_cats as $sub_sub_cat) {
                          $out_put.='<li>
                              <a href="'.get_term_link($sub_sub_cat).'">'.$sub_sub_cat->name.'</a>
                                  <small>('.$sub_sub_cat->count.')</small></li>';
                        }
                        $out_put.='</ul>';
                    }}
                $out_put.='</li>';
            }
            $out_put.='</ul>';
            }
        }
         $out_put.='</li>';
    }
}
$out_put.='</ul>';
return $out_put;
}
```

CSS for Category Tree

```
ul.category-tree {
margin: 0 10px;
}
 ul.category-tree li {
margin-bottom: 0px;
padding-left: 0px;
padding: 5px 0px;
}
ul.category-tree li a {
font-size: 13px;
color: #8a6741;
}
ul.category-tree li ul {
border-left: 1px solid #999;
list-style: none;
margin-bottom: 0px;
margin-left: 0px;
margin-top: 7px;
}
ul.category-tree li ul li {
line-height: 15px;
padding-left: 17px;
position: relative;
}

ul.category-tree li ul li:before {
  background-color: #999;
  content: "";
  height: 1px;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 12px;
  width: 11px;
}

ul.category-tree li ul li a {
color: #555;
font-size: 13px;
}
ul.category-tree li ul li ul li a {
color: #555;
}
.category-tree.list {
overflow: hidden;
 }
.category-tree.list li {
float: left;
width: 100%;
margin: 0px 15px;
}
.category-tree.list li li {
float: none;
width: auto;
margin: inherit;
 }
.category-tree small {
font-size: 11px;
float: right;
}
```

Now you can echo category_tree() where you like or modify if you like.

I have done this way.

Comment: This looks promising but it's just throwing an error for me. =/

Answer (score 1):

This is how I have dealt with this.

As I've said in my initial question, I'm not a great PHP programmer, but I think this is a pretty solid way to handle a taxonomy drill-down.

It uses the current URL that the user is on to extract variables for platforms and genres. (Ie: it puts the slug of each into a vairable)

I put the code for that in my functions.php file:

```
// I assign the variables a NULL value before the multiexplode function
// so that I can use them for if statements later.
$platforms = NULL;
$genre = NULL;

function multiexplode ($delimiters, $string) {

    $ready = str_replace($delimiters, $delimiters[0], $string);
    $launch = explode($delimiters[0], $ready);
    return $launch;

    }   

$requestURI = multiexplode(array("/", "?", "&"), $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); //cuts the array into sections for genre= and platform=
$requestURI = array_splice($requestURI, -2, 2); //drops blanks for "/" and "?"

foreach ($requestURI as $value) {
    $value = parse_str($value);
    }
unset($value);
```

And here is my archive.php file which handles the output for genre & genre children. The platform list is in a different file.

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<div class="center">
<div id="padding">

<?php
if ($genre != NULL && $platforms !=NULL) { // If ganre and platforms both have a value (meaning they were selected)

$args = array( 'taxonomy' => 'genre', 'parent' => 0 );
$terms = get_terms('genre', $args);

    foreach ($terms as $term) {

        $term_list .= '<li><a href="?platforms='.$platforms.'&genre='.$term->slug.'">'.$term->name.'</a></li>';
    }

    echo '<ul>';
    echo $term_list;
    echo '</ul>';

// then we display children of selected genre term
$getGenre = get_term_by('slug', $genre, 'genre'); // Get the term using the genre slug
$current_genre_id = $getGenre->term_id; // get the term ID 
$current_genre_name = $getGenre->name; // get the term name

$term_id = $current_genre_id; // what tax parent to query children from. In this case, whatever genre they've selected.
$taxonomy_name = 'genre'; // name of taxonomy 
$termchildren = get_term_children( $term_id, $taxonomy_name ); // get children



echo '<h1>Sub-Categories in Category: <span style="color: green">' . $current_genre_name . '</span></h1>'; 


echo '<ul>';
foreach ( $termchildren as $child ) {

    $term = get_term_by( 'id', $child, $taxonomy_name );

    echo '<li><a href="?platforms='.$platforms.'&genre='.$genre.'+'.$term->slug.'">' . $term->name . '</a></li>';
}
echo '</ul>';

?>


    <div id="postList">
    <?php if ( have_posts() ) { while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();?>
        <h2>Latest Entries</h2>
    <ul><a title="<?php the_title();?>" href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><li>
        <span class="image"><?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($page->ID, 'thumbnail'); ?></span>
        <span class="content">
        <h3><?php the_title();?></h3>
        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
        </span>

    </ul></li></a>
    <?php endwhile; } else { echo 'No posts to display.'; }?>
    </div>


<?php 
} else {
// They have only selected a platform
$args = array( 'taxonomy' => 'genre', 'parent' => 0 );
$terms = get_terms('genre', $args);

    foreach ($terms as $term) {

        $term_list .= '<li><a href="?platforms='.$platforms.'&genre='.$term->slug.'">'.$term->name.'</a></li>';
    }

    echo '<ul>';
    echo $term_list;
    echo '</ul>';

//wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => 'genres', 'container' => false, 'menu_class' => 'genres', 'depth' => 0));
?>

    <div id="postList">
    <h2>Latest Entries</h2>
    <?php if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <ul><a title="<?php the_title();?>" href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><li>
        <span class="image"><?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($page->ID, 'thumbnail'); ?></span>
        <span class="content">
        <h3><?php the_title();?></h3>
        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
        </span>
    </ul></li></a>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    </div>

    </div>
</div>
<?php } ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Now I just need to add check for the + symbol because it's not handling those properly once you drill all the way down into children, but that's not a big deal.

I'm not sure what to do about the bounty since I've essentially answered my own question. I'll leave it open until it expires I suppose, and if someone can give me a better answer that does everything I need it to do in a cleaner package, I'll reward it to them.

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be achieve with wordpress [taxonomy template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Custom_Taxonomies_display) and [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) function. you can do like that:

1.create a page template which list all terms in `platforms` taxonomy

2.create `taxonomy-platforms.php`.In this taxonomy template list all `genre` taxonomy terms which are parent terms ( `$term->parent==0` ).

3.create `taxonomy-genre.php`.In this taxonomy template test term is parent term  or sub-term

```
<?php
        $term_id = $wp_query->queried_object->cat_ID;
        $term=get_term($term_id,'genre');
        if(!$term->category_parent){
            get_template_part('content','parent-taxonomy');
        }else{
            get_template_part('content','sub-taxonomy');
        }
?>
```

if term is parent then `content-parent-taxonomy.php` is call, in which list all sub term of that taxonomy.while if it is sub then `content-sub-taxonomy.php` in which list all posts ( use global varible to pass, `platforms` taxonomy term you are searching/visiting and use it in loop for query).

Comment: I am trying this out now and will let you know how it goes! Thanks!

Comment: This is essentially what I'm talking about, except that with taxonomy term lists, they reset the query every time. I need them to append to the URL as the user drills down. Maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: Okay.. I think I have achieved my desired results using your suggestions and this code for the term lists: $term_list .= '<a href="' . $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] . '&genre=' . $term->slug . '">' . $term->name . '</a>';

Comment: glad to help :)